# Rendered image is different than Camera view

Tags: rendering, camera

I am new to Blender even to the world of animation.

I have 4 cameras and I have bind them with markers in the timeline. When I animate they change fine. When I open the Render view from the button side to the *Object Mode* button it shows perfect Camera view.

But when I Render it as png all the images are black, they are like a view from a camera just pointed towards ground but there is no other camera I have checked the Outliner list also.

I have also tried selecting the Border option in Render tab but when I click on Render or Animate, I get a message that border is not allowed for sequencer.

I have searched on google and all the solutions I am being told are not working.

Someone Please help me out.
Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: This is the camera view]

[image: This is the rendered image]

Comment: No it is not a duplicate as in VSE I added text using Effect Strip function, the texts are appearing properly in the set frame but objects are not visible. In some frames an object is partially visible only.

Comment: ok, check this list: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Thanks for the list but it also doesnt help. I am doing something wrong but what, this I am not able to understand.

Comment: Consider sharing your file (upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then paste the provided link, editing your question) as it would make your issue much more clear...

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help but I found what was wrong.

the Sequencer box was checked in Post Processing. So i just unchecked it and Checked the Border button and it is working fine now.

Comment: This is what was proposed in comments